# Change the way to load files from grunt-karma 0.9 to 0.10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, karma-runner

It there any change of the way to load files in karma.options.files property from version 0.9.x to 0.10.x?

in 0.9.x I have this code and works fine

```
prj: {
    src: 'src',
    test: 'test',
    jsPattern: '**/*.js',
    files: {
        src: ['<%= prj.src %>/<%= prj.jsPattern %>'],
        srcTest: ['<%= prj.test %>/<%= prj.jsPattern %>']
    }
},
karma: {
    options: {
        files: [
            '<%= prj.files.src %>',
            '<%= prj.files.srcTest %>'
        ]
    }
}
```

but in 0.10.1 give me this error

```
WARN [config]: Invalid pattern src/**/*.js!
    Object is missing "pattern" property.
WARN [config]: Invalid pattern test/**/*.js!
    Object is missing "pattern" property.
```

For fixing I have to change

```
prj: {
    src: 'src',
    test: 'test',
    jsPattern: '**/*.js',
    files: {
        src: '<%= prj.src %>/<%= prj.jsPattern %>',
        srcTest: '<%= prj.test %>/<%= prj.jsPattern %>'
    }
},
karma: {
    options: {
        files: [
            '<%= prj.files.src %>',
            '<%= prj.files.srcTest %>'
        ]
    }
}
```

And it works! but, 
How can include in `karma.options.files`  an array of patterns like in first example?